# How to use http in cloud9 ide?

Tags: cloud9-ide

I use `python manage.py runserver $IP:$PORT`, then start [this page](https://py3-pronan.c9users.io/). As you can see, clound9 uses https, which causes a problem - some css or js files can't be load from other sites via http.

the browser console shows:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://py3-pronan.c9users.io/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

This site is nothing special, I'm totally ok with http, so is there a way to configure cloud9 ide to use http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud9 routes both HTTPS **and** HTTP traffic to your server listening on 0.0.0.0:8080.

Therefore, all you need to use HTTP is to use http://... instead of https://... in your browser :)